# Is "Putting something in practice is good to bring out doubts" correct?

Tags: expressions

I think one good way of learning is by practicing because is during the practice, for example, in English, when you speak... it's that moment when the doubts arrive. I was wondering if the phrase below is ok, for Spanish people like me, dealing with phrasal verbs is complicated:

> Putting something in practice is good to bring out doubts.

(I want to emphasize that doubts arrive all of a sudden.)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. Can you elaborate on how "put something in practice" is related with "bring out doubts"? What do you mean by "bring out doubts"?

Comment: I mean: the effect of practicing something, makes you have more doubts, and it's by solving doubts that you gain experience. The thing is that I want to emphasize that the doubts arrive all of a sudden...

Comment: What do you exactly mean by using doubt? Do you mean if a person practice more, he or she will become more uncertain?

Comment: I think the best way to master something is to do it almost without thinking, following your natural instinct. So, practice english speaking for example, makes you doubt about what you are saying. I mean real situations, real practice results in wonderings you may not have in a narrower class context. You become uncertain but after looking for more information about the thing you have just said you learn a lot more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrasal verb *bring out* means to make more prominent. Cooking something a certain way might "bring out" the flavor. Paying someone a compliment might "bring out" the best in that person, or insulting somebody might "bring out" the worst.

So, if you want to emphasize how learners might become more unsure of themselves when you start using the language, I suppose you could say:

> *Putting something into practice is a good way to bring out doubts.*

However, the phrase "bring out doubts" is not very idiomatic, and it might be hard for someone to understand what you're trying to say without additional context.

I made a few slight changes to your original:

- I changed "putting something ***in*** practice" to "...***into*** practice..." (*into* is simply the [more natural preposition](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=put%20it%20in%20practice%2Cput%20it%20into%20practice%2Cput%20this%20into%20practice%2Cput%20this%20in%20practice&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), I think, but I'm not sure I'd go so far as to say that "in" would be wrong.)
- I changed "is good to" to "is a good way to" (I think the sentence flows better that way)

A better phrasal verb to use might be *bring forth*:

> *Putting something into practice is a good way to bring **forth** doubts.*

The phrasal verb "bring forth" means "to give rise to or introduce". I think that's a little bit closer to the meaning you are trying to express, that when you try putting something into practice, a lot of doubts might suddenly spring up.

One other very natural phrasing I thought of was:

> *Putting something into practice is a good way to bring **overcome** your doubt.*

That may be a true maxim, but it doesn't say what you are trying to express here.